# android navigating the values between the screen

Tags: android

In my application i want to call a web service on clicking the button(which is in 1st screen).In the first screen i will enter an input.
Based on that input value the web services has to function.After clicking the button i called an new intent and there the web service is called,but how can i pass the value from 1 screen to other.

My Code:

This is button click(1st screen)

```
public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
//              EditText medit;
//              EditText medit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), dispaly.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

This is web service(After clicking button)

```
medit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);  
             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                String weight = medit.getText().toString();
                String fromUnit = "Grams";
                String toUnit = "Kilograms";

                PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
                weightProp.setName("Weight");
                weightProp.setValue(weight);
//              weightProp.setValue(medit.toString());
                weightProp.setType(double.class);
                request.addProperty(weightProp);

                PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
                fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
                fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
                fromProp.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(fromProp);

                PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
                toProp.setName("ToUnit");
                toProp.setValue(toUnit);
                toProp.setType(String.class);
                request.addProperty(toProp);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
                try
                {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    Log.i("myApp", response.toString());  
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);
                    setContentView(tv); 

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `putExtra` in calling intent and get that intent in another screen .

For Example you can call like this .

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PlayVideoActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("KeyName", value);
    startActivity(myIntent);
```

now when another activity come get value like this .

```
 String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("Keyname");
```

this is example for use you can use type that support by putExtra for intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this. you can use putExtra or shared preferences.
  **SharedPreferences:**
  **To edit data from shared preferences**
       SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
       editor.putString("Name","Test");
       editor.commit();

**To retrieve data from shared preferences**

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);    
  String name = preferences.getString("Name","");    
  if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))  
  {   
      name = name+"  Sethi";  /* Edit the value here*/  
  }
```

OR

```
**putExtra:**

**pass data using putExtra at the time of calling intent.**

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PlayVideoActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("KeyName", value);
startActivity(myIntent);

**Retrive data  from other activity**

String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("Keyname");
```